# Deadbolt 2 Restrict function has only one possible failure code

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1, deadbolt-2

This question may have a bit of philosophical aspect to it.

I have been using Deadbolt 2 (Scala) in my Play application and it works quite well.

In looking at the [Restrict function definition](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/DeadboltActions.scala) (line 47)  I noticed that it will invoke the onAuthFailure for one of the following reasons:

1. No user in session (no subject)
2. Action specified no roles.
3. User attempted an action for which they did not possess one or more required roles.

In my application UI, I would like to receive a different status code for each of these so that a user that is not logged in (condition 1) will be redirected to login page but condition 3 would be more gracefully handled by just a warning (since they can do no harm anyway and might have accidentally tried to edit when they have 'read-only' access - perhaps a UI bug, but logging in again is a bit draconian).

If I had to settle for just 2 status codes, however, I would want to differentiate between 1 and the other 2.  I can see how this could be accomplished but would like to get other opinions on the merits of even doing this.

If I were to implement this change, it looks like I could just override the Restrict function in my own extension of the DeadboltActions trait.

I'm a little new to scala, so I'm open to additional ideas on how to best accomplish these goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just add the code to differentiate between condition 1 and either 2 or 3 as follows:

In MyDeadboltHandler:

```
class MyDeadboltHandler(dynamicResourceHandler: Option[DynamicResourceHandler] = None) extends DeadboltHandler {
...
  def onAuthFailure[A](request: Request[A]): Result = {
    Logger.error("authentication failure")
    val json = new JsonStatus("Failed to authenticate", -1).toJson.toString
    if(noUserInSession(request)){
      Results.Forbidden(json).withHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*")
    }
    else{
      Results.Unauthorized (json).withHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*")
    }
  }

  def noUserInSession(request:RequestHeader) = {
    username(request) match {
      case Some(u:String) => false
      case _ => true
    }
  }
```

This works well for me and does not impose upon the basic Deadbolt-2 functionality.

Comment: One thing that occurred to me with this issue is that there is a distinct difference between authentication and authorization.  A user can be Authenticated (logged in, using valid credentials) but might not be Authorized (does not have required roles for a specific action).

Comment: how to mock these functions when running scala Test